# select from table using comma separated string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a user table in which we store skills of a user that is a comma separated ids like ,These are primary key of skill table

```
'2,3,4,5'
```

and i have a search page,In which we have to search using the skills that also multiple entry, the data is like this

```
'2,3' or '3,4' or '6,7' or '2'
```

my question is how do i write the `where` clause any one please help 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Your database structure should be fixed. You need a junction table, called something like `UserSkills`, with one row per user and per id.

Here are some reasons:

- Storing *numbers* as *strings* is a bad idea. You should use the appropriate underlying types.
- Your skills are presumably references into another table. Foreign key references need to be of the same type as the thing they are referring to.
- SQL has excellent support for tables and mediocre support for strings, so you should use the appropriate data structure.

Answer (score 0):

All though this is not the right way to store forign keys in the dabase. However, per your problem, you might want to do something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE skill LIKE '%2, 3%';
```